# Jquery animate and pointer-events:none

Tags: jquery

I have two animations on two different divs in a container on hover.

```
<div class="thumbbox">
    <div class="thumbimg hover"></div>
    <div class="thumbtxt2"></div>
</div>
```

Here´s the fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/4hWbP/
The problem is, if I remove pointer-events:none on the overlaying div (.thumbstxt2),
it interferes with the hover and the animation gets buggy. Since IE doesn´t support pointer events, is there a way around this problem. Maybe a diffrent jquery code, I´m kind of a noob here.

PS: I also tried this, but it didn´t work:
http://jsfiddle.net/6PesR/1/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put class `.hover` on the container instead, and use following snippet then:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XAnpp/4/)

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function () {

    //THUMBNAIL HOVER
    $j(function () {
        $j(".hover").css("opacity", "1");

        $j(".hover").hover(function () {

            $j(this).find('.thumbimg').stop().animate({
                opacity: .5
            }, 200);

            $j(this).find('.thumbtxt2').stop().animate({
                left: 0
            }, 200);

        },

        function () {
            $j(this).find('.thumbimg').stop().animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 200);

            $j(this).find('.thumbtxt2').stop().animate({
                left: -220
            }, 200);

        });
    });

});
```